# how to set path for cron backup zip file

Tags: sh, cron

I have a shell script which is (stored in `/home/username/public_html/backup_dir/db_backup.sh`) used to take a database backup.

When I'm running the shell script in my *shared hosting* through putty by going to the directory `/home/username/public_html/backup_dir/` and then running the script through command `sh db_backup.sh` it is creating the zip file in `backup_dir` directory (good); but the same script when I'm running throught crontab it is createing the zip file in root (i.e. `/`) directory **(issue)**.

> I want the cron to creating the zip file in `/home/username/public_html/backup_dir/` where the shell script is.

I know I have to set the store path some where, but I don't know where to write it.

**Shell script (db_backup.sh)** :

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=my_db.sql.`date +"%Y%m%d"`
DATABASE=db_name
USER=db_username
PASS=db_password
unalias rm     2> /dev/null
rm ${FILE}     2> /dev/null
rm ${FILE}.gz  2> /dev/null
mysqldump --opt --user=${USER} --password=${PASS} ${DATABASE} > ${FILE}
gzip $FILE
echo "${FILE}.gz was created:"
```

**crontab command** :

```
0 */6 * * *  sh  /home/username/public_html/backup_dir/db_backup.sh
```

Any help/suggestion will help allot.

Thanks.

Comment: Noninteractive scripts normally do not have alias expansion, so the `unalias` is basically a no-op.

Comment: Also, `rm` takes an arbitrary number of file names, so you could do `rm -f "$FILE" "$FILE.gz"`.  The `-f` basically turns off "file not found" warnings as a side effect, so you should not need the error redirection then.

Comment: @tripleee: actually I'm dont know shell script, The mentioned code I found in google so used it. So should I replace 3 lines (starting with `unalias`) with `rm -f "$FILE" "$FILE.gz"` ?? and do I have to write `2> /dev/null` also.?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea; and no, you don't need the `2> /dev/null`, that's what "you don't need the error redirection" means.

Comment: thanks @tripleee, I'll replace it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this;

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=/home/username/public_html/backup_dir/my_db.sql.$(date +"%Y%m%d")
DATABASE=db_name
USER=db_username
PASS=db_password
unalias rm     2> /dev/null
rm ${FILE}     2> /dev/null
rm ${FILE}.gz  2> /dev/null
mysqldump --opt --user=${USER} --password=${PASS} ${DATABASE} > ${FILE}
gzip $FILE
echo "${FILE}.gz was created:"
```

Comment: thanks @Mustafa DOGRU, it works but the generated file is difference,and also gzip is not working i.e generated sql file is not compressing. New generated file name is **my_db_file.sql.Mon Oct 31 16:58:01 GMT 2016** and what I want is **my_db_file.sql.20161031.gz**.

Comment: and one more issue i notice after altering the file name as you have said, every-time when the cron runs it creates a new file, wreathed then replacing the existing one with same date.

Comment: @RaunakGupta; are you use date "%Y%m%d" in the script, your file output is timestamp. But this script only generate only date like 20161031. what is result date +"%Y%m%d" output in terminal. I updated ans. maybe this could help you. If you fix this, gzip command also work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Cron runs every job in the invoking user's home directory.  Apparently, you are running this out of `root`'s crontab.

The proper fix is probably to add the directory path to the script:

```
FILE=/home/username/public_html/backup_dir/my_db.sql.$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

or if you explicitly want to use the path name of the running script

```
FILE=$(dirname "$0")/my_db.sql.$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Less ideally, your script could explicitly `cd` to this directory before doing any actual work, but I would recommend against that because

- The script could end up failing to `cd` but still continuing (you can of course add `set -e` to make every failure fatal, but that would probably require some code changes elsewhere, too).
- If the intent is to always create the file in the same location, this should be made obvious to even an untrained eye.

Comment: Hi, @tripleee you answer worked, but I did't accepted your answer because the file name suffix was missing. btw thanks for such a detail answer.